# what to assign for name in @projection annotation

Tags: spring, annotations, spring-data-rest

I am newbie to Spring-data-rest. In my project instead of getting JSON instead of getting links while we make a REST call to the DB, i written the projections for repositories as follows. But for the name variable i assigned Tenant which is a table in my DB.  But even i give any name to the name field it is still working as same. What actually name filed in projection defines.

```
@Projection(name="Tenant", types= Binary.class)
public interface BinaryProjection {
String getId();
String getUsername();  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The name field is the URL parameter value that you would use to have this projection called and has nothing to do with your table name.

I'm assuming that your domain object is called Tenant, which maps to an underlying database table.  Your projection name should be something that describes what the project does (for the sake of whoever is writing the consuming code), and the types, should be the corresponding domain class:

```
@Projection(name="with-id-and-username", types= Tenant.class)
   public interface BinaryProjection {
   String getId();
   String getUsername();  
}
```

To have this projection uses, you would call something like:
http://localhost:8080/rest/Tenants?projection=with-id-and-username